# jsp:include position issue

Tags: jsp, include

i have a problem with jsp dynamically inclusion.
In other words i have one master jsp for templating, it includes two others jsp.
The included jsp contains SAP hbj taglibrary, the master JSP is pure JSP (1.2) code.

The problem is that included JSPs don't respect rendering order at runtime but they are rendered at top of the page.
I read some thread about this, but I don't find solutions .

May you help me, please ?

Thanks

```
    // Primo CASO:
// Compiling Exception:
// •    No renderer context available (a htmlb tag without a rendererContext attribute must be nested within a RendererContext tag)


// masterPage.jsp
<%@ taglib uri="tagLib" prefix="hbj" %>
<jsp:useBean id="myBean" scope="session" class="include.test.bean.MyBean" />
<hbj:content id="myContext" >
  <hbj:page title="PageTitle">
   <hbj:form id="myFormId" >

        <div>
        <p>IncludedPage1 Start</p>
            <jsp:include page="includedPage1.jsp" />
        <p>IncludedPage1 End</p>

        <p>IncludedPage2 Start</p>
            <jsp:include page="includedPage2.jsp" />
        <p>IncludedPage2 End</p>

        <p>IncludedPage3 Start</p>
            <jsp:include page="includedPage3.jsp" />
        <p>IncludedPage3 End</p>

        </div>


        <div>
            <h3><%="MyBean: " + myBean.toString()%></h3>
        </div>

   </hbj:form>
  </hbj:page>
</hbj:content>

//includedPage1.jsp
<%@ taglib uri="tagLib" prefix="hbj" %>
<jsp:useBean id="myBean" scope="session" class="include.test.bean.MyBean" />

<div class="radioCheck_elementContainer">
    <hbj:radioButtonGroup id="fldUteRegistrato" columnCount="2" selection="<%=myBean.getRadioButtonValue()%>">  
        <%fldUteRegistrato.setOnClick("onClickRadio");%>
        <hbj:radioButton id="fldUteRegistratoSI" text="SI" key="SI" tooltip="Registrato" disabled="FALSE" />
        <hbj:radioButton id="fldUteRegistratoNO" text="NO, procedere alla registrazione sul sito Poste.it da parte del Cointestatario" key="NO" tooltip="Non Registrato" disabled="FALSE" />
        <hbj:radioButton id="fldUteRegistratoNULL" text="NULL VALUE" key="NULL" tooltip="NULL VALUE" disabled="FALSE" />
    </hbj:radioButtonGroup>             
</div>

//includedPage2.jsp
<%@ taglib uri="tagLib" prefix="hbj" %>
<jsp:useBean id="myBean" scope="session" class="include.test.bean.MyBean" />

<% String ifldId = ""; %>
<hbj:inputField id="fldInputFieldPage2" type="string" maxlength="16" value="">
    <% ifldId = myContext.getParamIdForComponent(fldInputFieldPage2); %>
</hbj:inputField>



<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("ID CAMPO:" + <%=ifldId%>)
</script>

//includedPage3.jsp
<%@ taglib uri="tagLib" prefix="hbj" %>
<jsp:useBean id="myBean" scope="session" class="include.test.bean.MyBean" />

<hbj:inputField id="fldInputField" type="string" maxlength="16" value="" />


<% String avanti="";%>
<hbj:button id="cmdAvanti" text="Avanti" width="127" onClick="onCmdAvanti" design="EMPHASIZED" encode="True">
<%
    avanti = myContext.getParamIdForComponent(cmdAvanti);
%>
</hbj:button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("ID Pulsante:" + <%=avanti%>)
</script>

// Secondo CASO:

// Exception:
// •    Nessuna
// Comportamento:
// •    Solo I campi appartenenti al form da cui parte l’evento vengono inviati al server, la causa è la creazione di più form e quindi di conseguenza nell’HTTP request trovo solo i campi del form da cui è staqto effettuato il submit (Evento)

// masterPage.jsp
<%@ taglib uri="tagLib" prefix="hbj" %>
<jsp:useBean id="myBean" scope="session" class="include.test.bean.MyBean" />


        <div>
        <p>IncludedPage1 Start</p>
            <jsp:include page="includedPage1.jsp"  flush="true" />
        <p>IncludedPage1 End</p>

        <p>IncludedPage2 Start</p>
            <jsp:include page="includedPage2.jsp"  flush="true" />
        <p>IncludedPage2 End</p>

        <p>IncludedPage3 Start</p>
            <jsp:include page="includedPage3.jsp"  flush="true" />
        <p>IncludedPage3 End</p>

        </div>


        <div>
            <h3><%="MyBean: " + myBean.toString()%></h3>
        </div>




//includedPage1.jsp
<%@ taglib uri="tagLib" prefix="hbj" %>
<jsp:useBean id="myBean" scope="session" class="include.test.bean.MyBean" />

<hbj:content id="myContext1" >
  <hbj:page title="PageTitle1">
        <hbj:form id="myFormId" >
        <div class="radioCheck_elementContainer">
            <hbj:radioButtonGroup id="fldUteRegistrato" columnCount="2" selection="<%=myBean.getRadioButtonValue()%>">  
                <%fldUteRegistrato.setOnClick("onClickRadio");%>
                <hbj:radioButton id="fldUteRegistratoSI" text="SI" key="SI" tooltip="Registrato" disabled="FALSE" />
                <hbj:radioButton id="fldUteRegistratoNO" text="NO, procedere alla registrazione sul sito Poste.it da parte del Cointestatario" key="NO" tooltip="Non Registrato" disabled="FALSE" />
                <hbj:radioButton id="fldUteRegistratoNULL" text="NULL VALUE" key="NULL" tooltip="NULL VALUE" disabled="FALSE" />
            </hbj:radioButtonGroup>             
        </div>
        </hbj:form>
    </hbj:page>
</hbj:content>
includedPage2.jsp
<%@ taglib uri="tagLib" prefix="hbj" %>
<jsp:useBean id="myBean" scope="session" class="include.test.bean.MyBean" />

<hbj:content id="myContext2" >
  <hbj:page title="PageTitle2">
        <hbj:form id="myFormId" >
        <% String ifldId = ""; %>
        <hbj:inputField id="fldInputFieldPage2" type="string" maxlength="16" value="<%=myBean.getInputFieldValuePage2()%>">
            <% ifldId = myContext2.getParamIdForComponent(fldInputFieldPage2); %>
        </hbj:inputField>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("ID CAMPO:" + <%=ifldId%>)
        </script>

        </hbj:form>
    </hbj:page>
</hbj:content>


//includedPage3.jsp
<%@ taglib uri="tagLib" prefix="hbj" %>
<jsp:useBean id="myBean" scope="session" class="include.test.bean.MyBean" />


<hbj:content id="myContext3" >
  <hbj:page title="PageTitle3">
        <hbj:form id="myFormId" >
            <hbj:inputField id="fldInputField" type="string" maxlength="16" value="<%=myBean.getInputFieldValue()%>" />

            <% String avanti="";%>
            <hbj:button id="cmdAvanti" text="Avanti" width="127" onClick="onCmdAvanti" design="EMPHASIZED" encode="True">
            <%
                avanti = myContext3.getParamIdForComponent(cmdAvanti);
            %>
            </hbj:button>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("ID Pulsante:" + <%=avanti%>)
            </script>
        </hbj:form>
    </hbj:page>
</hbj:content>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("ID Pulsante:" + <%=avanti%>)
</script>

// Appendice:

// MasterPage.java
package include.test;

import include.test.bean.MyBean;
import com.sapportals.htmlb.*;
import com.sapportals.htmlb.enum.*;
import com.sapportals.htmlb.event.*;
import com.sapportals.htmlb.page.*;
import com.sapportals.portal.htmlb.page.*;
import com.sapportals.portal.prt.component.*;

public class MasterPage extends PageProcessorComponent {

    public DynPage getPage() {
        return new MasterPageDynPage();
    }

    public static class MasterPageDynPage extends JSPDynPage {

        private MyBean myBean = null;

        private void initBean() {
            IPortalComponentSession componentSession =
                ((IPortalComponentRequest) getRequest()).getComponentSession();
            Object o = componentSession.getValue("myBean");
            if (o == null || !(o instanceof MyBean)) {
                myBean = new MyBean();
                componentSession.putValue("myBean", myBean);
            } else {
                myBean = (MyBean) o;
            }

        }

        public void doInitialization() {
            IPortalComponentSession componentSession =
                ((IPortalComponentRequest) getRequest()).getComponentSession();
            Object o = componentSession.getValue("myBean");
            if (o == null || !(o instanceof MyBean)) {
                myBean = new MyBean();
                componentSession.putValue("myBean", myBean);

            } else {
                myBean = (MyBean) o;
            }
            myBean.setMethod("doInitialization");
        }

        public void doProcessAfterInput() throws PageException {
            initBean();
            InputField ifld = (InputField) getComponentByName("fldInputField");

            if(ifld!=null && ifld.getValue()!=null) {
                myBean.setInputFieldValue(ifld.getValue().toString());
            }
            else {
                myBean.setInputFieldValue("NULL VALUE");
            }


            RadioButtonGroup radioButtonGroup = (RadioButtonGroup) getComponentByName("fldUteRegistrato");

            if(radioButtonGroup!=null && radioButtonGroup.getSelection()!=null) {
                myBean.setRadioButtonValue(radioButtonGroup.getSelection());
            }
            else {
                myBean.setRadioButtonValue("NULL");
            }

            InputField ifld2 = (InputField) getComponentByName("fldInputFieldPage2");

            if(ifld2!=null && ifld2.getValue()!=null) {
                myBean.setInputFieldValuePage2(ifld2.getValue().toString());
            }
            else {
                myBean.setInputFieldValuePage2("NULL VALUE");
            }

            myBean.setMethod("doProcessAfterInput");
        }

        public void doProcessBeforeOutput() throws PageException {
            this.setJspName("masterPage.jsp");
        }

        public void onClickRadio(Event event) {
            initBean();
            myBean.setEvent("onClickRadio");
        }

        public void onCmdAvanti(Event event) {
            initBean();
            myBean.setEvent("onCmdAvanti");
        }
    }
}

//MyBean.java
package include.test.bean;


import java.io.Serializable;

public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    private String event = "";
    private String inputFieldValue = "";
    private String inputFieldValuePage2 = "";
    private String radioButtonValue= "";
    private String method = "";


    public String getEvent() {
        return event;
    }
    public void setEvent(String e) {
        event = e;
    }


    /**
     * @return
     */
    public String getInputFieldValue() {
        return inputFieldValue;
    }

    /**
     * @param string
     */
    public void setInputFieldValue(String string) {
        inputFieldValue = string;
    }

    /**
     * @return
     */
    public String getRadioButtonValue() {
        return radioButtonValue;
    }

    /**
     * @param string
     */
    public void setRadioButtonValue(String string) {
        radioButtonValue = string;
    }




    /**
     * @return
     */
    public String getInputFieldValuePage2() {
        return inputFieldValuePage2;
    }

    /**
     * @param string
     */
    public void setInputFieldValuePage2(String string) {
        inputFieldValuePage2 = string;
    }


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    public String toString() {
        return "MyBean [method=" + method + ", event=" 
+ event + ", inputFieldValue=" + inputFieldValue 
+ ", inputFieldValuePage2=" + inputFieldValuePage2
            + ", radioButtonValue=" + radioButtonValue + "]";
    }
    /**
     * @return
     */
    public String getMethod() {
        return method;
    }

    /**
     * @param string
     */
    public void setMethod(String string) {
        method = string;
    }

}
```

Comment: Switch the line 34 of the first JSP with the line 53, and set the display CSS property of div "foo" to "block".